# Java Ws Catch Interceptor Error

Tags: java, web-services, jboss, cxf

Am trying to catch a web service error but not able too, how can I catch this error?
Please note that am using Java-Ws(not Spring) and JBoss

```
11:19:54,457 WARNING [org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain] 
(http--0.0.0.0-8080-1) Interceptor for {http://services.com/}OppService#{http:
//services.com/}getopp has thrown exception, unwinding now:
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Unmarshalling Error: Not a number: asdas
```

If I sent it a number everything is working fine, but I want the code to break so I can catch the error, the problem is I can't seem to catch it since it doesn't reach the java code nor the handler.  The error is even before the handler.

Please note that am suing Java annotation to build the wsdl

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [DefaultValidationEventHandler](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/helpers/DefaultValidationEventHandler.html). As per docs:

> Receive notification of a validation warning or error. The
>   ValidationEvent will have a ValidationEventLocator embedded in it that
>   indicates where the error or warning occurred. If an unchecked runtime
>   exception is thrown from this method, the JAXB provider will treat it
>   as if the method returned false and interrupt the current unmarshal,
>   validate, or marshal operation.

So basically what you need to do is to extend that class, override `handleEvent(ValidationEvent event)` method and check for e.g.:

```
if (event.getSeverity() == ValidationEvent.WARNING) {
    return super.handleEvent(event);
} else {
    throw new RuntimeException("build your own message.");
}
```

Comment: i created a class and extended it as you said and added a breakpoint, but sadly it is not firing

Comment: How are you exposing your endpoint? Are you using Spring for that? In order it to be called you have to register the handler in your jax-ws properties at server side.

Comment: am using Java webservice and webmethod annotation and they are doing all the work of exposing the endpoint and what not... no am not using spring, i just realized that my HeaderHandler is being called, i thought it wasn't. the defaulyValidationEventHandler is still not working tho. I used <javaee:handler-chain><javaee:handler>
<javaee:handler-class>